# Automatic cell format to money

Tags: c#, datagridview, format

I try to make a automatic format system for money, for example: to digit the number 5124.25

the user types 5: 0,05

the user types 1: 0,51

the user types 2: 5,12

the user types 4: 51,24

the user types 2: 512,42

the user types 5: 5124,25

I need to put this "format style" in one column of datagridview, for this, I try this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (temp.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            e.Control.PreviewKeyDown -= Control_PreviewKeyDown;
            e.Control.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(Control_PreviewKeyDown);
        }
    }

    void Control_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)sender;
        TextBoxMoeda(ref temp, e);

        /*if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("escape pressed");
        }*/
    }

    public static void TextBoxMoeda(ref DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl txt, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        string n = string.Empty;
        double v = 0;
        try
        {
            n = txt.Text.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("R$", "");
            if (n.Length == 0)
                txt.Text = "0,00";
            else if (n.Length == 1)
                txt.Text = "0,0" + n;
            else if (n.Length == 2)
                txt.Text = "0," + n;
            else if(n.Length > 2)
                txt.Text = n.Substring(0, n.Length - 2) + "," +
                n.Substring(n.Length - 2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "TextBoxMoeda");
        }
    }
```

How It's possible to make this dinamic format for money ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the DefaultCellStyle.Format to "c" for money or whatever format you want, and then subscribe to the CellFormatting event:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Column2"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
dataGridView1.CellFormatting += dataGridView1_CellFormatting;
```

Try parsing the information into a decimal for your formatting:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
                                  DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.CellStyle.Format == "c" &&
      e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex) {
    decimal d;
    if (e.Value != null && decimal.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out d)) {
      e.Value = d.ToString("c");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this,but, work just when the user finish the number input, I need to format cell on the fly, when user enter with one new number, the cell is formated...

Comment: @Alexandre I would avoid that if possible.  What if the user tries to paste information from the clipboard?  Lots of edge cases, etc.

Comment: I lock the ctrl+v... the user need to type the value...
my system work and not work... the function "TextBoxMoeda" not work :(